# How yarn.lock knows what version to resolve?

Tags: node.js, semantic-versioning, yarn-lock.json

I have a project with several microservices, each of them have a package.json.

In all of them I have a sequelize package that I want to be updated to the latest minor/patch version, so I used the caret sign in my package.json files:

```
"sequelize": "^6.21.4"
```

Each of those package.json have a different version for the sequelize package, when I run yarn install, my yarn.lock will look like this:

```
sequelize@^6.21.2, sequelize@^6.21.4, sequelize@^6.25.2:
  version "6.31.1"
```

But searching for the latest minor/patch version of sequelize in npm, it gives me 6.35.2.

What is the criteria of yarn for choosing the resolve version?

Why yarn.lock not giving me the latest minor/patch version as a resolve version?

Comment: `yarn why pack1`. `0.6.2` is **not** compatible with a `^0.1.x` semver.

Comment: @jonrsharpe This command returned me the microservices that the package is being used. Why is not compatible? I mean, I thought the caret sign means all versions until 1.0.0, excluding this major version

Comment: See https://semver.org/, https://semver.npmjs.com/, https://classic.yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/dependency-versions/#toc-caret-ranges

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks, when I created the question I put random versions just to be more clear, I thought 0.x.x versions have the same behavior but they have not, I updated the question with the real package and versions but I still don't get why the resolve version is 6.31.1 and not the latest

Comment: I'd imagine `6.31.1` was the latest version that met all of those requirements **at the time it was installed**, and if you deleted the lockfile and reinstalled it _would_ resolve to `6.35.2`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe It worked, now they all are in 6.35.2, I thought a new yarn.lock will be generated every time I run a 'yarn install' but only a few modifications were made, now yarn.lock changed completely.

Comment: No that's **exactly the opposite** of what the lockfile is for, the whole point of it is to ensure the dependency tree is reproducible. Note rather than deleting and starting over you should use e.g. https://classic.yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/cli/upgrade/ to manage your dependencies.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Right, but how we update packages then? I mean, once in a while someone has to update the lockfile and we get stuck with this lockfile until the next lockfile is updated, ensuring everyone is using the same package versions for a while?

Comment: Yes, that's what's supposed to happen. You have consistent versions _until you choose otherwise_, at which point you use the Yarn CLI to apply the changes you want to the lock and maybe package file.